# Object passed by reference will not exist. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, reference, pass-by-reference

I have an array.

```
var array:[customType] = [] // pseudo code

func Generate_New_Array(){
    //initialization of generatedNewArray
    array = generatedNewArray
    for (index,element) in array{
         async_process({
         Update_Data_From_Web(&array[index])
         })
    }
    })
}

func Update_Data_From_Web(inout object:customType){
     download_process{
          object = downloadedData
     }
}
```

The question is , what will should I do if I call Generate_New_Array before Update_Data_From_Web will finish for each of elements. They will store value back to not-existing index in array. How to avoid problems with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. Make the `Generate_New_Array` process cancelable, and then cancel the old one before starting the new one.
2. Make the `Generate_New_Array` serial so that when you make a subsequent call to this method, it will finish the calls first. For example, you could have this enqueue an operation on a serial queue.

Regardless of which approach you adopt, if this is multithreaded code, make sure you synchronize your interaction with the model object (via GCD queues or locks or whatever).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, the issue is that I am not sure how to stop the async request, because it's BaaS's provided api ( and there is no cancel query method) . Is there any way to track a thread name to be able to terminate it?

Comment: No, if they don't provide an cancelation API, then you can't safely cancel it. But your example suggests that you're creating a bunch of individual requests, so assuming it makes sense to control the degree of concurrency (e.g. if you have 100 requests, but only 5 reasonably can run at a time, you can set up pattern so you at most have to only wait for the five current ones to finish rather than waiting for all 100). It's hard to advise further without more details about the API you're calling.